# MSGraph API returning 401 and 403 to an authorized service using sdk

Tags: c#, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to use the graph api in an application at my company. I've confirmed I have the required permissions but I only get 401 unauthorized and 403 Forbidden responses.

using Microsoft.Graph version 5.41.0 and Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient version 2.17.0

Here is a simplified code sample of how I am implementing it.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "$$$";
var clientId = "$$$";
var clientSecret = "$$$";
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var photoStream = await graphClient.Users["{userId}"].Photo.Content.GetAsync();
```

I've tried to trouble shoot with gpt, and have tried various code samples from SO and ms docs. Perhaps i am not creating the bearer token properly.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which permission did you grant for the app? What kind of permissions? Delegated or application?

Comment: pls firstly checking if your code could work well by `await graphClient.Users["{userId}"].GetAsync();
` and pls checking if you already consent Application type of permission `User.Read.All`, here's the API document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#to-retrieve-the-profile-photo-of-a-user

Comment: @user2250152 User.Read and User.Read.All both Delegated

Comment: It should be application, because you authenticate with client secret

Comment: @user2250152 Yep, after i read your first response i immediately investigated and solved by changing delegated to application! thanks user!